# What does the hash code have to do in this Flutter Redux example

Tags: flutter, redux, flutter-redux

I am looking at [this example](https://brainsandbeards.com/blog/ultimate-redux-guide-for-flutter)

```
@immutable
class UserState {
  final bool isLoading;
  final LoginResponse user;

  UserState({
    @required this.isLoading,
    @required this.user,
  });

  factory UserState.initial() {
    return new UserState(isLoading: false, user: null);
  }

  UserState copyWith({bool isLoading, LoginResponse user}) {
    return new UserState(
        isLoading: isLoading ?? this.isLoading, user: user ?? this.user);
  }

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      identical(this, other) ||
          other is UserState &&
              runtimeType == other.runtimeType &&
              isLoading == other.isLoading &&
              user == other.user;

  @override
  int get hashCode => isLoading.hashCode ^ user.hashCode;
}
```

What does a hashCode have to do with this? What is it used for? (I have shortened the code because I get a stackoverflow error that I am posting mostrly code)

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeing this here as the class overrides the `==` operator.

One should always override `hashCode` when you override the `==` operator.
The `hashCode` of any object is used while working with Hash classes like [HashMap](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-collection/HashMap-class.html) or when you're converting a list to a set, which is also hashing.

more info:

1. https://medium.com/@ayushpguptaapg/demystifying-and-hashcode-in-dart-2f328d1ab1bc
2. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/override-equalsobject-hashcode-method/
   explains with Java as the programming language but should hold good for dart.